# MYSQL returning result even if wrong value supplied

Tags: mysql

I don't know if this is a bug or what. I have a simple MYSQL table called `table` with column called `id` which is `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`

I have a row with id `1` and when I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '1dasfrf'
```

And surprisingly it returns row id `1` as a result row! It should return nothing as an invalid value is supplied. MYSQL table type is `innoDB` if that is relevant

So in short if you put any non number value after the row value, it will return that row. This is of course with all id values not just `1`

Comment: It gets even worse:  `create table foo (id varchar(20)); insert into foo values ('1x'),('xy');delete from foo where id;'

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. A lot of "magic" happen behind the scenes.
In this case, you can read about conversion here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/type-conversion.html

If you do not want automatic type conversion you can use strict mode: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: so is there any solution for this?

Comment: Updated with suggestion.

Comment: Strict mode will not change the behaviour in the question.

Comment: According to the documentation `STRICT_ALL_TABLES`: Invalid data values are rejected.

Comment: However, if you validate user input this wouldn't be a problem.